# Using logical indexing on a specific set of rows in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I want to return the rows in a cell array which meet a condition that is repeated every few (but variable) lines. For example if my data is x,y,z coordinates split up into i slices where each slice{i} is a specific z I could have something that looks like this.

```
1,3,10
1,4,10
1,5,10
2,3,10
2,4,10
3,1,10
```

For each x I want to return the rows containing the max and min y values. So in this case I want rows 1, 3, 4, 5, 6.

The code I have now looks like this

```
idx = slice{i}(start:finish,2) == miny | slice{i}(start:finish,2) == maxy;
return = slice{i}(idx, :);
```

But the line slice{i}(idx, :) looks through the entire array from the beginning. I want to restrict this line to a certain subset.

Something like

```
slice{i}(idx, start:finish)
```

but this doesn't work.

Am I missing some syntax or do I need to approach the routine in a different way? (I know I haven't provided enough information for help in changing approach but I am assuming there is some way to do this by restricting the row indicies)

edit:

I found a workaround by creating

```
dummy = slice{i}(start:finish, :);
```

and then just returning over the dummy matrix.

Comment: As a start can you use cell2mat to convert to numeric array? That's easier to work with.

Comment: Agree with Benoit on this one. So, any particular reason for having a cell array to store such a data?

Comment: No reason - just found it easier to work slice by slice in the cell array. I'll take a look to see if it's any easier with numeric, I just thought I was missing a straightforward bit of code

Comment: Is the first row, i.e. X always sorted?

Comment: for each slice (z) yes. So in the cell array it is sorted in every slice{i}. However, now looking in the numeric array it is sorted for every identical z. And I just have the same problem with the final line of code...how do I restrict it to the start and finish position in a numeric array?

Comment: you mean column though right? x values are in the first column

Comment: Sorry my bad, yes I meant first column for X coordinates. So, let me ask you, if you do something like `slice_num = cell2mat(slice)`, does it work?

Comment: Yes - but I already had it stored as a numeric array too. The issue I am coming across using both structures for the data is restricting the indexing to looking between the start and finish indicies instead of starting from row 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you -

```
%// Convert slice to a nuemric array
slicenum = cell2mat(slice)

%// Create the offset arary to be added with the local max-min indices to
%// get the global(actual) row indices for idexing into slicenum or slice
offset1 = [0 ; find(diff(slicenum(:,1)))]

[~,~,unqX] = unique(slicenum(:,1))

%// Get local max and min row indices
max_row_ind = accumarray(unqX,slicenum(:,2),[],@max_ind) + offset1
min_row_ind = accumarray(unqX,slicenum(:,2),[],@min_ind) + offset1

%// Get global row indices and use them to index into slicenum for the output
max_y_slice = slicenum(max_row_ind,:)
min_y_slice = slicenum(min_row_ind,:)
```

Associated functions -

```
function ix = max_ind(array1)
[~,ix] = max(array1);
return;

function ix = min_ind(array1)
[~,ix] = min(array1);
return;
```

Comment: Error using accumarray
First input SUBS must contain positive integer subscripts.
Error in stackhelp (line 5)
max_row_ind = accumarray(slicenum(:,1),slicenum(:,2),[],@max_ind) + offset1

Comment: @browser So do you have X coordinates as `0`'s too?

Comment: around 0, x steps from -0.111 to 0.089, However, I would need the code to also handle the scenario if there were 0s

Comment: Error using  + 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
Error in stackhelp (line 11)
max_row_ind = accumarray(unqX,slicenum(:,2),[],@max_ind) + offset1

Comment: @browser Give us `whos slicenum` info?

Comment: slicenum      5552x4             177664         double

Comment: I found a workaround (see edit in question). Thanks for all the effort, it is really appreciated. And that offset code is very useful so thanks for that!

Comment: @browser If you are still interested in `accumarray` based solution, which must be a fast solution, could you give us `size(unqX)` info. Also, since you had XYZ, I was expecting `Nx3` size for `slicenum`, not sure how did it end up as `Nx4` array. Any ideas on that too?

Comment: size(unqX) is 5552 x 1. Ah yes, sorry that's my fault. I had simplified the problem when asking the question. It's xyzI with intensity in the fourth column. Sorry about that